# Remove punctuations from the end of a string (and not from the middle)

Tags: python, string, replace, translation

How can I get rid of the punctuations only from the end of a string?

For example, in the below code I want `'A-BC'` from variable `s` and `t`, but my code only returns `'ABC'`.

```py
import string

s = 'A-BC/'
t = 'A-BC-'

s.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
t.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `str.rstrip()`:

```
>>> import string
>>> s = 'A-BC/'

>>> s.rstrip(string.punctuation)
'A-BC'
```

Please refer [`str.rstrip()` document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) for more details.